# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout

Tags: android, progressdialog, illegalstateexception

Within the last days I do see increasing error messages that sound identical. I don't use tablets ActionBar - I'm developing for phones only.

What's the reason for these crashes?

Here's a complete trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=8995, result=0, data=null} to activity {xy.yyyy.app.android/xy.yyyy.app.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2818)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2861)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout
at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.init(ActionBarImpl.java:214)
at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.<init>(ActionBarImpl.java:200)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:255)
at xy.yyyy.app.MyProgressDialog.show(MyProgressDialog.java:33)
at xy.yyyy.app.MyProgressDialog.show(MyProgressDialog.java:23)
at xy.yyyy.app.Main$FetchTask.onPreExecute(Main.java:19)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:549)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:499)
at xy.yyyy.app.Main.onActivityResult(Main.java:60)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4581)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2814)
... 11 more
```

This is a typical AsyncTask that I use from within an activity to start a lengthy task with a ProgressDialog:

```
private class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute () {
    if (!isRunning) {
      progressDialog = MyProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,
                                             null,
                                             null,
                                             true,
                                             false);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(final Void... strings) {
    Boolean rc = false;

    if (!isRunning) {
      isRunning = true;

      processDelete();
    }

    return rc;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
      progressDialog.cancel();
    }
    progressDialog = null;

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();

    isRunning = false;
  }
}
```

Here's my MyProgressDialog class:

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {

  public MyProgressDialog(final Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.MyProgressDialog);
  }

  public static MyProgressDialog show(final Context context, final CharSequence title, final CharSequence message) {
    return show(context, title, message, false);
  }

  public static MyProgressDialog show(final Context context, final CharSequence title, final CharSequence message, final boolean indeterminate) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
  }

  public static MyProgressDialog show(final Context context, final CharSequence title, final CharSequence message, final boolean indeterminate, final boolean cancelable) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
  }

  public static MyProgressDialog show(final Context context, final CharSequence title, final CharSequence message, final boolean indeterminate, final boolean cancelable, final OnCancelListener onCancelListener) {
    MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(onCancelListener);
    dialog.setTitle(title);

    dialog.addContentView(new ProgressBar(context), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dialog.show();

  return dialog;
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here's the used style:

```
<style name="MyProgressDialog">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Here's a screenshot of that ProgressDialog:

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

Had to add this to the style:

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: Thanks to Google reneging on their open-source commitments there's no way to look at ActionBarImpl.java to find out what's going on. First thought: what styles have you got in R.style.MyProgressDialog? Try passing 0 instead of this in the constructor, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Did add the style to my question. Unfortunately I don't get that error - even when testing in tablet emulator. I only see that error in crashes that were reported by users using real devices.

Comment: Heh, that's a very unorthodox dialog, just a progressbar in empty space! I expect the framework is barfing on one those null window attribute values. Suggest you create an alternative version of your <style> without those nulls and put it in res/values-v11/ so it only gets applied to your dialog on Honeycomb or later.

Comment: That dialog theme style is totally broken.  Just to start, you need to have it inherit from one of the base dialog themes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This did work for all Android releases up to 3.x. What should I do on 3.x to get a rotating cycle without border, background etc. like shown in the picture. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could get it to work on all platforms when adding  parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" to the MyProgressDialog style. I would like to give the bounty reputation to hackbod but this is not possible without an answer. So if you want ...

Comment: See how to use actionbar in a dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment