# Full Screen DialogFragment (over ActionBar) in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fullscreen, android-dialogfragment

Im having some problems in show DialogFragment in Full Screen. In my application, i have an Fragment that when you click in some button it calls a DialogFragment. But the DialogFragment just fills the area of the Fragment (below the action bar). I would like it fills all the screen like that: http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/8682/myimage2.png

Any help?

```
     public class ItensActivity extends Fragment {
             ... 
            public void openDialogItens()
            {       
                dialog = new ItemDialog();      
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
                getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();  

            }

            public static class ItemDialog extends DialogFragment
                {


                   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                   @Override
                   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());        
                      builder.setView(getContentView());
                      Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                      WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                      lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                      lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                      lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
                      dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                      dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);   
                      return dialog;
                  }

            private View getContentView() {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_item, null);
                   return view;
            }
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want, but if you want a "fullscreen" Fragment, why would you use a DialogFragment? Use a normal Fragment instead.

Comment: It's because i want show it like a popup/dialog, showing what's in its back, something like that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uV5Jd.png. But the DialogFragment isn't covering the actionbar

Comment: So... You don't want a *fullscreen* Dialog, but a Dialog that partially covers your ActionBar, right?

Comment: If the dialog would be called by the main activity, it would work. But by the Fragment it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after search a lot, i didn't find anyway to make the DialogFragment overlays the actionbar using API 5. But i find a alternative way to do that making the Fragment calling a new activity on the screen with the theme of a dialog. This solution help me a lot, so, im sharing it here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275009/2327056

> @StrikeForceZero using the idea from a google group post I was able to pull it off
>   styling an activity. you would want to modify the height and width to
>   a "dynamic" size of your choice preferably. Then set whatever
>   ActionBar buttons you would like
>
> ```
> <style name="PopupTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
>     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
>     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
>     <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
>     <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> --

```
public static void showAsPopup(Activity activity) {
    //To show activity as dialog and dim the background, you need to declare android:theme="@style/PopupTheme" on for the chosen activity on the manifest
    activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    LayoutParams params = activity.getWindow().getAttributes(); 
    params.height = 850; //fixed height
    params.width = 850; //fixed width
    params.alpha = 1.0f;
    params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: put this in `DialogFragment`
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Wallpaper);
 }
 `

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.frame_help);
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flag you dialog fragmet to use Dialog instead of embedded fragments when calling #show.

```
myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog")
```

This will create a dialog that will overlay on top of actionbar and status bar (which you can manually add back in if you wish).