# Change android:Theme.Dialog to Light AppCompat Dialog

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using in my style.xml as main app theme

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

And all AlertDialogs using same  white/blue colors. But i have Activities which working as Dialog `parent="android:Theme.Dialog"` and this box use **dark** theme. How could I change it to `AppCompat.Light` theme?
I tryed `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` but as you know it doesn't working well. 
Thanks.

Comment: doesn't working well => Then what's happening? Any issue or error?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog">
```

Or this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

 <style name="MyAppCompatDialogTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

[source last code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453939/android-app-compat-theme-dialog-when-large)