# Howto combine windowIsFloating with ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am stuck combining windowIsFloating with an Activity which should have an ActionBar.

I want to have an Activity which looks like a popup, thats why i am using a theme for it which has:

`<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>`

but this seems to cause problems, because as soon as it is set i get a *java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout*

What i want to achive is a popup-like view containing an ActionBar, which can reuse my apps themes and styles. Is there a way to acive it or do i have to try to fake the look of an action bar with a custom view? Is any of the free ActionBar implementations suited for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a way to achieve this. Basically the solution works around the constraints enforced by the ActionBarView on the styles attribute **android:windowIsFloating**. The solution is very good described in [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275009) here on StackOverflow.

Additionally I put together a [sample project](https://bitbucket.org/johanols/android-dialog-activity) based on the code found in that particular post for everybody to check out.