# Activity icon for style Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.MinWidth

Tags: android, dialog, styles, android-actionbar, icons

This is the style for my activity

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.MinWidth">
  <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large</item>
  <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

and it is correctly displayed as a not full screen dialog, as desired.
I'd like to display an icon also to the left of the activity title but I cannot figure out how.
Thanks in advance.

PS
minSdkVersion 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use that style, Android will use a [layout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml) that doesn't include an `ImageView` for an icon. However, you can call `TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` using the `TextView` that displays the title to show your icon. [Otherwise you might look into an implementation like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275009/420015).

**Implementation**:

```
    final TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
        title.setCompoundDrawablePadding(30);
        title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.your_icon, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

**Results**

[image: Example]