# Up ActionBar action on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-actionbar-compat, dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` that is styled to full screen using `setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_App)`.

The `DialogFragment` shows fine but the up action (the `homeAsUp` action on the ActionBar) does not work. I tried implementing `onOptionsItemSelected` in the `DialogFragment` but it is never called.

Is there a way to get the up action callback in the DialogFragment so I can dismiss it ? For reference, I'm using `ActionBarCompat`.

Comment: what is the up action?

Comment: Are you showing actionbar on the dialog ?

Comment: Indeed. It shows the ActionBar when I set that style. The style is the same for my activities.

Comment: are you looking for this kind of dialog??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment

Comment: @Saad Farooq try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33080474/1118886) solution. this is a workaround but it just might solve your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to attach an `ActionBar` to the `DialogFragment` even though you can set the theme of the `DialogFragment` it will not register as a `ActionBar` to it, `Dialog.getActionBar()` will always return null.

Instead of getting the `ActionBar` you can always attach a Layout that will look like an ActionBar and set the functionality on it using menu.

The other way is to create an activity  with actionBar as a Dialog you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the right answer currently

Comment: There is a way, to attach toolbar instead, which works about the same as actionbar. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38917527/878126

Comment: "the most recent features are added to the support library's version of Toolbar, and they are available on any device that can use the support library.
For this reason, you should use the support library's Toolbar class to implement your activities' app bars." https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Answer (score 21):

This wasn't possible but there is a workaround for this using a`Toolbar`. Now you can include `Toolbar` as part of your `DialogFragment` `layout xml` and can set its design/icon according to your needs. You will also need to implement `setNavigationOnClickListener` if you want the back button to behave like it does normally. See the sample class below.

```
package com.package.name;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private View parentView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar);
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //The layout xml file contains the toolbar
        parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment_createpost, container, false);
        initView();
        initData();
        return parentView;
    }


    private void initView() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) parentView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    }

    private void initData() {
        toolbar.setTitle("Post");
        //Set naviagtion icon to back button drawable
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// handle back button naviagtion
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for the DialogFragment to receive calls to `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` you need the set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the onCreate() method of the Fragment.

Another potential solution is to handle the up action in the activities `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` callback. Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just delegate the up action from the component, that receives it (i.e. the parent Activity or Fragment), to your DialigFragment. When up occurs, check if your DialogFragment is shown and if so, call the apropriate method.

Answer (score 2):

Check out  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032956/action-bar-back-button-not-working) for detailed description.

I solved these problem by adding the below coding.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: 
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In **MainActivity**:

Previously,

> public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity

Then I change into

> public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity

Most probably you need to extend an `MainActivity to FragmentActivity.`

Comment: Wait ?? You get that callback in the `DialogFragment` ??

Comment: @SaadFarooq yes In DialogFragment you have to use intent to pass it to that activity for Action bar navigation button.

Comment: No go... And where is the intent?

Comment: @SaadFarooq firstly you need to go through these link.Read the questions and answers posted by me. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032956/action-bar-back-button-not-working`.Then check out the answer.In `GalleryFragment` you see the `Intent`.For Eg: you have to use `intent` in `Fragment` Code then pass it to `Activity` code.In `Activity` Code you have to set the `homeAsUp action button`.Then in `Manifest` you have to set these `Activity Name`.That`s it.

Comment: @SaadFarooq Simply use the intent like these. `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class); startActivity(intent);` in `onClick` or `onItemClick` method in Fragment code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nope... it's never called. And the argument to `navigateUpFromSameTask` can't be a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 1):

define toolbar in layout and call it on your dialog fragment

```
Toolbar toolbar=dialog.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                           toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
                          toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View view) {
                                  dialog.dismiss();
                              }
                          });
```