# Can I design a customized size activity in Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android

Normally, a activity will display a maximum screen.  I hope to display a window with width 400px and height 500px, but the following is still display a full window, why?

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World OK!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To KeLiuyue

Thanks! but your code doesn't work, the window is full screen after run your code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val m = windowManager
        val d = m.defaultDisplay
        val p = window.attributes
        p.height = dp2px(this, 500f)
        p.width = dp2px(this, 400f)
        window.attributes = p

    }

    private fun dp2px(context: Context, dp: Float): Int {
        val scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
        return (dp * scale + 0.5f).toInt()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you only need to add the following to you application theme:

```
<!-- Your application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Your arguments -->
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#isFloating%28%29):

> Flag indicating whether this is a floating window. Maybe a boolean
>   value, such as "true" or "false".

This means that your activity will be placed over the screen with the size you want. Check the above demo for a testing app the I have created.

### Demo

[image: App with windowIsFloating]

---

For more info on how to implement, check this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275009/1574250

Comment: @HelloCW have this fixed your issue?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible, and it's very simple! In your manifest change the application theme to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
```

And you should get an application which has dimensions of your root layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your code

```
WindowManager m = getWindowManager();
Display d = m.getDefaultDisplay();
android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getWindow().getAttributes();
p.height = dp2px(this,500);
p.width = dp2px(this,400);
getWindow().setAttributes(p);
```

**And convert `dp` to `px`**

```
private int dp2px(Context context, float dp) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Could you give me a full code? I can't test your current code.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: I test your code .And it was ok. And I use
 `<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>` in the `manifest` . I didt not set the` theme`@HelloCW

Comment: You can download source code to test, https://www.dropbox.com/s/yt9xcciael0q463/CustomizeWindow.zip?dl=0